# Close Vote invalidated?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I recently saw this question [Why didn't Lisa Simpson become an atheist?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110012/why-didnt-lisa-simpson-become-an-atheist) which, to my mind, seemed to be asking for opinions and I voted to close as such.

I understand that others might disagree as to my opinion and that is what the review queue is for.

However, the close votes (and mine was not the only one) seem to have disappeared when I checked back.

Can someone please explain what happened here?

*As an aside, and possibly related, I did flag a somewhat contentious comment and this has now been removed...did this influence anything?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the revision history, there's no special magic going on here, the question was closed and then reopened by the moderators. Specifically, I reopened the question since it doesn't really seem opinion-based at all. It's asking for an apparent contradiction that a user saw between a character's actions when compared to what they know (or think to know) about the rest of the character's background. It explains *why* they think it was unusual for Lisa to become Buddhist when looking at her character. That seems a common character-motivation question asking for explanations based on the TV-show, rather than asking out of the blue why she wouldn't convert to anyone's favourite religion.

Though, I usually try to leave a comment under the question when correcting a review mistake like that, but the question was reopened so quickly, that I just deemed it better not to spotlight the closure too much and confuse the asker with why people closed their question. But in light of the downvotes it's gathering, for possibly the same reasons, it might have been a better idea to make a case for the question in the comments.

Like you said, the review queue is for reviewing questions for closing and sometimes reviewers can disagree or err. The comment flag you issued didn't have much to do with that (other than indirectly making me aware of the question's closure). In fact I deemed the comment flag valid once another comment arrived that proved the prognosticated discussion that would appear reality.

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand that the moderator's viewpoint.

Comment: @Paulie_D I should have left a comment under the question, though, I'll probably do that now.